# How do I fix holes in an organic form and how did this even happen?

Tags: mesh, objects, vertices

So I'm learning Blender and I tried making a human body for pretty much the first time today. I was pretty content with the body and went to add legs with the Boolean modifier. So two uv-spheres per leg and I unified everything together (I did'nt know how to mirror objects so I eyeballed it but I think they were pretty equal).
So I sculpt at the thighs and butt area and it's going fine, I zoom out and suddenly the two spheres of each leg were seperated except at one point on the side.
Here's what I tried:
-sculpting on top of the sphere to fill out the seperation (didn't work)
-cutting the lower sphere off, which resulted in a big hole on each side about where the knee should be

so I tried filling the holes by clicking 4 or 3 points and F and it did fill the hole (kinda tedious) so I did it on the other side but now the legs weren't symemetric. I tried to ignore it and just add new spheres but when I sculpted on top of those, it was super unsymmetric!

So removed the lower spheres again and I thought maybe I could fix it if I do another equal cut a bit more above but I could already see that it had uneven points so I'd end up with the same problem.

I hope someone knows what I mean, I sadly saved after deleting the lower spheres so now the holes are my starting point. Does it have to do with where the object sits on the grid? Does the object have to be exactly in the middle so it can symmetrize on the x-axis?

Are there some good tutorials for fixing big holes in organic forms? I don't really want to start this new as I'm actually pretty satisfied so far but would it be better if I did? I'm scared that something like this would happen again and I woulnd't know what to do.

I don't really know how to explain my problem better so if you have any questions I'll try my best to answer them. I'm sorry if this is hard to read haha :'D

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Pictures

[image: After trying to fix holes (1)]

[image: After trying to fix holes (2)]

Trying to fix holes (1,2) The holes themselves (3,4)

[image: holes]
[image: holes]

Comment: Hi and welcome, but... a few images are often better than a long speech ... especially in a 3D world

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to explain it. Would pictures be better?

Comment: Yes... pictures are always better.

Comment: I added some! I hope it's better now :)

Comment: With brush like Snake Hook you can create holes if you press ctrl, I guess you can only fix that in Edit mode with F. If you've lost symmetry and want to recreate it, go in Edit mode, select all, go in the header menu > Mesh > Symmetry and choose the axis in the Operator box (on the bottom left of your 3D view). The position of your object on the grid has nothing to do with it, symmetry uses the object origin as center of the symmetry.

Comment: By the way: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post